# JSON file printed with bars separating fields

Tags: java, json

I need to send a minified JSON to a rest service, it seemed all right, however, when printing my JSON into a file several "/" slashes appear separating the fields from the file, as I am new to this type of implementation I was confused ...

Basically, I add objects to a list and at the end, I convert the generic list to Json, this is my method that converts the List object to JSON

```
public String convertListToJson(List obj) throws IOException {
    String jsonInString = null;
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.setDefaultPropertyInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS);
    mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.USE_EQUALITY_FOR_OBJECT_ID, true);
    jsonInString = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(obj);
    JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readValue(jsonInString, JsonNode.class);
    String json = jsonNode.toString();
    return json;
}


String payload = convertListToJson(object);
        System.out.println(payload);
```

This is the result of printing on the console

```
 [{"id":12,"nomePeriodo":"2012","inicio":"2012-01-01T02:00:00Z","fim":"2012-12-31T02:00:00Z"},{"id":13,"nomePeriodo":"2013","inicio":"2013-01-01T02:00:00Z","fim":"2013-12-31T02:00:00Z"},{"id":14,"nomePeriodo":"2014","inicio":"2014-01-01T02:00:00Z","fim":"2014-12-31T02:00:00Z"},{"id":15,"nomePeriodo":"2015","inicio":"2015-01-01T02:00:00Z","fim":"2015-12-31T02:00:00Z"},{"id":16,"nomePeriodo":"2016","inicio":"2016-01-01T02:00:00Z","fim":"2016-12-31T02:00:00Z"},{"id":17,"nomePeriodo":"2017","inicio":"2017-01-01T02:00:00Z","fim":"2017-12-31T02:00:00Z"},{"id":18,"nomePeriodo":"2018","inicio":"2018-01-01T02:00:00Z","fim":"2018-12-31T02:00:00Z"}]
```

This is the method I use for printing to file

```
 printJson(payload);
     private void printJson(String payload) {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            try {
                mapper.writeValue(new File("c:\\server\\JSON.json"), payload);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

When I print to a file this is the result:

```
"[{\"id\":12,\"nomePeriodo\":\"2012\",\"inicio\":\"2012-01-01T02:00:00Z\",\"fim\":\"2012-12-31T02:00:00Z\"},{\"id\":13,\"nomePeriodo\":\"2013\",\"inicio\":\"2013-01-01T02:00:00Z\",\"fim\":\"2013-12-31T02:00:00Z\"},{\"id\":14,\"nomePeriodo\":\"2014\",\"inicio\":\"2014-01-01T02:00:00Z\",\"fim\":\"2014-12-31T02:00:00Z\"},{\"id\":15,\"nomePeriodo\":\"2015\",\"inicio\":\"2015-01-01T02:00:00Z\",\"fim\":\"2015-12-31T02:00:00Z\"},{\"id\":16,\"nomePeriodo\":\"2016\",\"inicio\":\"2016-01-01T02:00:00Z\",\"fim\":\"2016-12-31T02:00:00Z\"},{\"id\":17,\"nomePeriodo\":\"2017\",\"inicio\":\"2017-01-01T02:00:00Z\",\"fim\":\"2017-12-31T02:00:00Z\"},{\"id\":18,\"nomePeriodo\":\"2018\",\"inicio\":\"2018-01-01T02:00:00Z\",\"fim\":\"2018-12-31T02:00:00Z\"}]"
```

So you have these \ bars separating the items in json...
Am I doing something wrong or is this common? 
If possible I would like to remove them from my archive

Comment: Why are you using an ObjectMapper again when you're writing to a file? You've already converted your payload into a string - don't you just want to write that string straight to a file?

Comment: @JonSkeet
Truth! I'm doing it again!Thanks

Comment: Those bars are called back slashes and are used to espace special characters such as double quotes (`"`). Jon already hinted at the why, i.e. you let the ObjectMapper write a String to the file and thus it will treat the entire string as _one_ Json value and will escape all the double quotes in the string to  `\"` (In most cases that escaping is needed if text values contain quotes or double quotes, e.g. `"fullName":"Thomas \"Tom\" Whoever"`).